# Want to refresh a div after submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple form and a `<div>` container. My problem is I'm trying to refresh the div when i submit the form.

```
<div id="refresh">
   FOO FOO FOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
</DIV>

 <form  id="test">
    <input type="text" name"testFI">
    <input type="submit" id="postB"  value="Post" />
 </form>
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: @Mr.Alien, I had to use "****". OP need to know abusive word doesn't help

Comment: What about using search field on SO, this has been asked hundred times before... But be aware, if you submit the FORM, page is reloaded

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific. Do you want to update the div and also post the form, update the div instead of posting the form, or posting the form and update the div with the result?

Comment: I'm posting the form with Jquery ! and that's working well but i also want to update the DIV just after the submitting the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/)'s [post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#example-7), an AJAX shorthand method to load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.

Here's an example to **Post a form using ajax and put results in a div** from their site:

```
<form action="/" id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search...">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    // Attach a submit handler to the form
    $( "#searchForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get some values from elements on the page:
        var $form = $( this ),
            term = $form.find( "input[name='s']" ).val(),
            url = $form.attr( "action" );

        // Send the data using post
        var posting = $.post( url, { s: term } );

        // Put the results in a div
        posting.done(function( data ) {
            var content = $( data ).find( "#content" );
            $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be:

```
<form id="testContent" onsubmit="testContent()">  //id is important! :P

<script type="text/javascript">
    function testContent() {
        //test your content
        //update your div

        return false;    //you can cancel the submit by returning false
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you don't cancel FORM submitting here, you need if using online script: `onsubmit="return testContent()"`. But better would be to not use online script

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   document.forms['test'].onsubmit = function(){ 
      document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML = "some content";
      return false;
   }
</script>
```

Placed **under** your form and div markup.

Comment: @ShivamSomvanshi - "Not working" is not a good description. For others to help, you need to describe what *is* happening instead, as well post any error messages appearing in your javascript debugging tools.

Comment: Not working to do what exactly ? Your q is how to 'refresh the div when i submit the form' - you do not provide any more context to your question. This is a literal answer - interpreting "refresh' in this example as changing the contents. ( that's all )

Comment: Looks like this answer was accepted, might be best to create a new question, Provide more information in it. It sounds like you need to use AJAX and you are using jquery , tell us these things if you are. We can't guess what you want to do : )