# How to refresh only div on submit button click?

Tags: html

I have 2 div in my web page. what I need is submit only form_div when press the submit button.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="form_div">
<form name="form">
<input type="submit" name="save" id="save"/>
</form>
</div>
<div id="other_div"></div>
</div>`
```

Comment: You can check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646154/want-to-refresh-a-div-after-submit-the-form

Comment: For others to help, you need to show your effort

Answer (score 0):

In jquery,

you could call

```
$("your-custom-selector").click(function(){
//Do-whatever. This code only runs when your customselector is pressed.
});
```

In JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("your-custom-selector").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    //Do-whatever. This code only runs when your customselector is pressed.
}
```